# How to set skin at runtime in Flex 4

Tags: runtime, flex4, skin, gumbo

I have a bunch of custom controls based on a SkinnableContainer.

When adding the control at design time, I can specify a skin by using the skinClass attribute on the tag.

I need to add some of these elements during runtime, and I can't figure out how to specify the skinClass for my controls.

eg.

```
var something:CustomThing = new CustomThing();

/* mistery code here to attach the skin ? */

addElement(something);
```

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

mmmmm, found it actually.. have to set a style..

```
something.setStyle("skinClass", MySomethingSkinClass);
```